# Access to value of variable with dynamic name

Tags: python, variables, dynamic

I found several topics where discussed that dynamical creating of single variables in loops is bad practice and better use dictionary.

In my case I don't need create them dynamically, I want ***access*** them in the loop.

***I don't want to use dictionary*** for them, because these variables are used in lot of places in code, and only in one place I need such dynamic access.

Idea example:

```
car_pos = 1; man_pos = 10
car_vel = 100; man_vel = 5

for elm in ['car', 'man']:
    elm_pos = elm + '_pos'
    elm_vel = elm + '_vel'
    # I want values of elements with such names here
    print(elm_pos, elm_vel)

# Desired output:
# (1, 100)
# (10, 5)
```

Answer (score 4):

Variable names are a terrible way to relate pieces of information. There is nothing linking `man_pos` and `man_vel` except that they both happen to start with `man`. Other than that they are totally separate. Python has better ways of bundling elements like these together.

In this case, `man` and `car` should be objects with attributes `pos` and `vel`.

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, pos, vel):
        self.pos = pos
        self.vel = vel

# assume that both men and cars move only in one dimension
man = Thing(10, 2)   
car = Thing(100, -5)
```

Then your loop is simply:

```
for item in [car, man]:
    print(item.pos, item.vel)
```

Do not do it the way you're trying to do it. It will only lead to tears -- if not yours, then of the people who have to look at your code.

Comment: That example was just to show idea, in actual code situation is much more complex. Also, I am study python right now and want to know if such idea can be realized.

Comment: If the situation is more complex, then that is an even better reason not to do it. And *of course* you can do it, but for the love of Guido,don't!

Comment: What if I have lot of code where these variables were already defined and work that non-optimal way and I need to receive their values in my piece of code without global refactoring of all the code?

Comment: Then you should globally refactor all of the code so it won't make the baby Guido cry. The fact that you have made mistakes already is not an excuse to make more. Look up the concept of "technical debt."

Comment: I should add: there is a name for the process in which you discover that you have made mistakes that you really ought to fix before proceeding further. It is known as "programming."

Answer (score 2):

Just use the globals() dictionary, with key as your variable names. The value for these keys would be the actual value of these variables.

```
car_pos = 1; man_pos = 10
car_vel = 100; man_vel = 5

for elm in ['car', 'man']:
    elm_pos = elm + '_pos'
    elm_vel = elm + '_vel'

    print(globals()[elm_pos], globals()[elm_vel])
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with everything that kindall said. However, you can try named tuple to go the non dictionary route...

```
from collections import namedtuple
data = namedtuple('data',('pos','vel'))
car = data(1,100)
man = data(10,5)


for elm in (car,man):
    print(elm.pos,elm.vel)
```

Comment: It seems likely that a man or car's position or velocity may change, so I ruled out `namedtuple` for that reason.

Comment: @kindall Yup, that makes sense. I didn't take that into account.