# How can I convert a range of ints to strings to be used for variables?

Tags: python, variables, range

So I have a few variables that use numbers at the end of the string. But the "i" doesn't seem to convert to a string when I use an str function. Any idea why this might be?

code:

```
has_GroupConnection1 = True
has_GroupConnection2 = True
has_GroupConnection3 = True

GroupConnection1 = 45
GroupConnection2 = 88
GroupConnection3 = 55

for i in range(1,3):
    if str(has_GroupConnection[i]) == True:
         print(str(GroupConnection[i]))
```

Comment: Replace `GroupConnection1`, `GroupConnection2`, and `GroupConnection3` with a list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to value of variable with dynamic name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177693/access-to-value-of-variable-with-dynamic-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you're *trying* to do, but you can't do it (mostly, see below). Your code as-written de-sugars to:

```
has_GroupConnection.__getitem__(i)
# foo[x] -> foo.__getitem__(x)
```

since `has_GroupConnection` isn't defined in your program, this will never work and instead will throw a `NameError`. You could define it, though.

```
has_GroupConnection = []
has_GroupConnection.append(None)  # 0th element
has_GroupConnection.append(True)  # 1st element
has_GroupConnection.append(True)  # 2nd element
has_GroupConnection.append(True)  # 3rd element
# or indeed has_GroupConnection = [None, True, True, True]
# or a dict will work, too...

# as above...
GroupConnection = [None, 45, 88, 55]

for i in range(1,3):  # note this is only [1, 2], not [1, 2, 3]
    if has_GroupConnection[i]:
         print(str(GroupConnection[i]))
```

---

My first sentence is an oversimplification, you *can* do it using `eval` or `locals()`, but it's a Bad Idea, so I won't show you how to do that and will strongly admonish you not to do so! It's ugly, inefficient, and an awful code smell (and you should be ashamed of yourself for thinking about googling it!)

Comment: @TomKarzes fixed, dunno what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using lists using a tuple

```
group_connection = list()
group_connection.append((True, 45))
group_connection.append((True, 88))
group_connection.append((True, 55))

for i in range(0,len(group_connection)):
    if (group_connection[i][0] == True):
         print(str(i) + " has the connection number " + str(group_connection[i][1]))
```

Outputs

```
0 has the connection number 45
1 has the connection number 88
2 has the connection number 55
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
has_GroupConnection = [True] * 3
GroupConnection = [45, 88, 55]

for i in range(3):
    if has_GroupConnection[i]:
         print(GroupConnection[i])
```

The output is:

```
45
88
55
```

Both `has_GroupConnection` and `GroupConnection` are both now lists, so you an index into them with `[]`.  I changed the loop to run from 0 to 2.  The original loop ran from 1 to 2.  I also eliminated some unnecessary things.

Answer (score 0):

This would be "a" way to approach your problem.

```
has_connections = [True, True, False]
group_connections = [45, 88, 55]

for h, g in zip(has_connections, group_connections):
    if h:
        print(g)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider the use of a dictionary here for storing these values (nested for the 'has' and 'connection' attributes) as then you'll have no problem cycling through the keys.

If you need to include the specific numbers, use a string replacement:

for i in range(1,3):

while connection-dict['GroupConnection%s' % str(i)]['has']:

print(dict['GroupConnection%s' % str(i)]['conn-number'])

Answer (score 0):

the syntax `[]` is used to specify an element in an iterable, like a list or a string, or to retrieve a value from a `dict`.  You're trying to use it to identify a variable, but that won't work. You should probably use a `dict`, instead:

```
group_connections = {
    1 : None,
    2 : 45,
    3 : 88,
    4 : 55      
}
```

Then you can just iterate through the `dict`'s keys to get all of your `GroupConnection`s:

```
for grp in group_connections:
    if group_connections[grp]:
        print(group_connections[grp])
```

Or you could use the `dict.items()` method:

```
for grp_number, connection in group_connections.items():
    if connection:
        print(connection)
```

Since your two pieces of data are related, it makes more sense to keep them together so they're related in some fashion.